# Using File to create directory which contains periods

Tags: java, file-io

```
File testDir = new File("C:\temp\test");
testDir.createNewFile();
```

As I understand it, the above will create a *directory* called test in the directory c:\temp

```
File testDir = new File("C:\temp\test.dir");
testDir.createNewFile();
```

As I understand it, the above will create a *file* called test.dir in the directory c:\temp

What should I be doing to the code above if I wish for test.dir to actually be a *directory*?

Comment: Side note .. instead of putting the path separator in the file itself, you can use File.separator so that it works on DOS or Unix systems alike.

Answer (score 8):

No, the first one will create a regular file - after all, that's what you asked it to do:

> Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist. The check for the existence of the file and the creation of the file if it does not exist are a single operation that is atomic with respect to all other filesystem activities that might affect the file.

Nothing there says it will create a *directory*. You'll want to escape the backslashes though, or it's trying to find `C:<tab>emp<tab>est`

If you want to create a directory, use `File.mkdir` or `File.mkdirs()`. You'll still need to escape the backslashes:

```
File testDir = new File("C:\\temp\\test.dir");
bool created = testDir.mkdir();
```

(Use `mkdirs` to create parent directories as well.) The return value tells you whether or not it actually created a directory.

Answer (score 2):

That's not true.

`File.createFile()` will create a file.

`File.mkdir()` creates a directory.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> File testDir = new File("C:\temp\test");
> testDir.createNewFile();
> ```
>
> As I understand it, the above will
>   create a directory called test in the
>   directory c:\temp

Wrong - it will create file called "test". Files do not *have* to have a "filename extension".

To create a directory:

> ```
> testDir.mkdir();
> ```

BTW, this kind of question is most easily and quickly answered by looking at the [API doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/). Do yourself a favor and get familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks again for your help chaps. I didn't spot that mkdir function down the bottom there! :-(